# What is the meaning of 'Contenido de serie crudo'?

Tags: significado, artes-visuales

Netflix associates tags with its TV series and movies, such as "sci-fi" and "comedy". Using the Spanish UI, I have seen one TV series (Toy Boy) tagged as "crudo". What does that word mean in this context? Looking at the possible meanings of crudo in the [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/crudo) , the closer I see is:

> 9. adj. Cruel, áspero, despiadado.

Is that the intended meaning here? If so, I guess that "harsh" or "rough" would be good translations to English?

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe you should update the question and give a couple examples of titles where you have seen that tag. When you hear "la **cruda** historia de ..." definitely has that meaning. It could also mean "foul language". See [lenguaje crudo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_soez)

Comment: @Diego Thanks! I have added the name of the TV series in which I have seen that tag to my question

Comment: If I browse through Netflix I see this series in Spain are tagged as _Descarnada_ and _De suspense_. Changing the language to English shows 'Gritty'. The full link to the gender is https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/100044, can you confirm is the one you have in your case?

Comment: @fedorqui That's exactly the genre. However, I see "crudo" instead of "descarnada" here in Brazil, I can only guess that Netflix has different translations for Latin America and Spain. Anyway, the first definition of "descarnada" in DLE is "Dicho de una expresión o de un asunto: Crudo o desagradable, expuesto sin paliativos", so I guess both words are synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right about 'crudo' meaning 'cruel, áspero, despiadado', which is something like harsh or rough.

To confirm the meaning, see how this genre is named [Gritty in Netflix's UI in English](https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/100044). And *gritty*'s translation to Spanish is, for this context, 'crudo, rudo' ([WordReference on Gritty](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=gritty)).

In more literal contexts, 'crudo' can mean *raw*, as in 'Esta carne está cruda'.